# got a macbook pro 2010 6,2... can i use ram from 6,1 macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, repair

I've got to send my 2010 macbook pro 6,2 in for repairs.  The MLB tested bad in the apple store.  They'll replace that and anything else that's wrong for a flat $310, which seems like a fair price.  The catch for me is that I upgraded to 8gb non-apple ram, and they're telling me that if I send it in, I may or MAY NOT get my ram back- they might very well put in original 4gb of apple ram, and not give me my 8gb sticks back.  Ludicrous if you ask me...

A friend has two sticks of 1 gb apple ram for a 6,1 macbook...  will this at least work with my computer so that I can send it in to be repaired?

the RAM sticks read:  1GB 2Rx16 PC3-8500S-7-10-A1 made by hynix

Answer (score 1):

Ludicrous for sure.  Though it does seem to be a fair price.

The Macbook Pro 6,1 and 6,2 both use the same spec RAM, 1066 MHz PC3-8500 DDR3 SDRAM.  The 1GB sticks should work in your laptop, assuming they are still functional.

Put the 1GB sticks in and hope they replace them with 2GB modules.